Expected input batch_size (3) to match target batch_size (1)
Context:

Image Captioning model via PyTorch
Fine-Tune with 1 image and a list of captions
Converting the image

Error with prints that show that the size and shape are the same
Before Outputs size:  torch.Size([3, 9956])
Before Outputs shape:  torch.Size([3, 9956])
Outputs size:  torch.Size([1, 3, 9])
Captions size:  torch.Size([1, 3, 9])
Captions shape:  torch.Size([1, 3, 9])
Outputs shape:  torch.Size([1, 3, 9])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Documents/projects/anothertry/pytorch-tutorial/tutorials/03-advanced/image_captioning/finetuneme.py", line 169, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "/home/Documents/projects/anothertry/pytorch-tutorial/tutorials/03-advanced/image_captioning/finetuneme.py", line 124, in main
    loss.backward()
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 525, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 267, in backward
    _engine_run_backward(
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/autograd/graph.py", line 744, in _engine_run_backward
    return Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Expected input size [3, 9], got [3, 9, 256]


Code:
    model = FineTuneModel(args.embed_size, args.hidden_size, vocab_size, args.num_layers)
    model = model.to(device)

    encoder = EncoderCNN(args.embed_size).to(device)
    decoder = DecoderRNN(args.embed_size, args.hidden_size, len(vocab), args.num_layers).to(device)
    
    
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    params = list(decoder.parameters()) + list(encoder.linear.parameters()) + list(encoder.bn.parameters())

    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params, lr=args.learning_rate)

    for epoch in range(args.num_epochs):
        model.train()
        total_loss = 0
        for i, (images, captions) in enumerate(dataloader):
            images = images.to(device)
            captions = captions.to(device)


            lengths = [len(cap) for cap in captions]
            outputs = model(images, captions, lengths)
            print("Before Outputs size: ", outputs.size())
            print("Before Outputs shape: ", outputs.shape)
            linear = nn.Linear(9956, 9).to(device)
            
            outputs = linear(outputs)
            outputs = outputs.unsqueeze(0)
            captions = captions.to(dtype=torch.float32)
            #outputs = outputs.view(3, 9)
            print("Outputs size: ", outputs.size())
            print("Captions size: ", captions.size())
            print("Captions shape: ", captions.shape)
            print("Outputs shape: ", outputs.shape)
            loss = criterion(outputs, captions)
            model.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            
            optimizer.step()

            total_loss += loss.item()
            print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{args.num_epochs}], Loss: {total_loss/len(dataloader)}')

        torch.save(model.decoder.state_dict(),
                os.path.join(args.fine_path,
                                'decoder-1-1.ckpt'))

        torch.save(model.encoder.state_dict(),
                os.path.join(args.fine_path,
                                'encoder-1-1.ckpt'))

In case it's needed too (my encoder & other):
transform = transforms.Compose([ 
                transforms.Resize((args.crop_size)),
                transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=3),
                transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(), 
                transforms.ToTensor(), 
                transforms.Normalize((0.485, 0.456, 0.406), 
                                    (0.229, 0.224, 0.225))])
# THE IMAGE IS GRAYSCLAE (cctv) AND THE MODEL IS TRAINED TO RGB IMAGES, SO I NEED TO #CONVERT TO GRAYSCALE BY DOING tansforms.Grayscale(....)

class EncoderCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_size):
        super(EncoderCNN, self).__init__()
        resnet = models.resnet152(pretrained=True)
        modules = list(resnet.children())[:-1]
        self.resnet = nn.Sequential(*modules)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(resnet.fc.in_features, embed_size)
        #self.bn = nn.BatchNorm1d(embed_size, momentum=0.01)
        self.bn = nn.LayerNorm(embed_size)

    def forward(self, images):
        with torch.no_grad():
            features = self.resnet(images)
        features = features.reshape(features.size(0), -1)
        features = self.bn(self.linear(features))
        return features

If I change to this:
           loss = criterion(outputs.squeeze(0), captions.flatten()) the error changes to:
Expected input batch_size (3) to match target batch_size (27)`. on `line 122, in main
    loss = criterion(outputs.squeeze(0), captions.flatten())

And if I do outputs = outputs.view(3, 9) the error changes to:
File "/home/es/Documents/projects/anothertry/pytorch-tutorial/tutorials/03-advanced/image_captioning/finetuneme.py", line 122, in main
    loss = criterion(outputs, captions)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1532, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1541, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home//anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 1185, in forward
    return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home//anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 3086, in cross_entropy
    return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: Expected input batch_size (3) to match target batch_size (1).

PS: Don't mind the file paths, I'm deleting the username.
